# NextJs. + Framer-motion - Warning: Prop `className` did not match

Tags: next.js, frontend, framer-motion

Made this AnimatedLetter component with framer motion that animates each individual letter from a string to make them appear from the bottom with a stagger effect. But I'm receiving this error :

*Warning: Prop `style` did not match. Server: "display:inline-block;transform:translateY(400px) translateZ(0)" Client: "margin-right:;display:inline-block;transform:translateY(400px) translateZ(0)"*

Here is the component. I'm supposing that the issue is coming from the marginRight I manually had in case of a space but don't really know how to solve it, if anyone could send some help, that'd be very appreciated :)

```
const AnimatedLetters = ({
  title,
}) => {
  const letterAnim = {
    hidden: { y: 400 },
    show: {
      y: 0,
      transition: {
        ease: ease,
        duration: duration,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <motion.span
      variants={containerAnim}
      initial="hidden"
      animate={start && "show"}
      key={title}
    >
      {[...title].map((letter, idx) => (
        <motion.span
          key={`letter${idx}`}
          variants={letterAnim}
          style={{
            marginRight: letter === " " && spacing,
            display: "inline-block",
          }}
        >
          {letter}
        </motion.span>
      ))}
    </motion.span>
  );
};

export default AnimatedLetters;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by refactoring the component and removing this nasty "spacing" prop that added a random space between words.

Here is what I changed :

```
const AnimatedLetters = ({
  title,
}) => {
  [...]
  const words = title.split(" ")

  return (
    <motion.span
      variants={containerAnim}
      initial="hidden"
      animate={start && "show"}
      key={title}
    >
       {words.map((word) => (
        <span key={word}>
          {[...word].map((letter, idx) => (
            <motion.span key={`letter${idx}`} variants={letterAnim}>
              {letter}
            </motion.span>
          ))}{" "}
        </span>
      ))}
    </motion.span>
  );
};
```

Cheers :)